# Почему java не является полностью компилируемым языком?

Tags: java, jvm

Я хотел бы узнать, почему java не является полностью компилируемым языком.
Да, я слышал "write once - run everywhere", но java требует разные реализации VM для разных архитектур.
Мы можем назвать C++ кроссплатформенным языком, потому что он имеет компиляторы для разных ОС и архитектур.

Comment: Какое определения для "полностью компилируемый язык" вы используете? Ответ зависит в первую очередь от этого.

Comment: то что у с++ есть компиляторы для разных ОС и архитектур, не делает его кросс-платформенным. Весь смысл не менять/переписывать код под разные ОС и архитектуры. На с++ этого не всегда можно достичь.

Answer (score 2):

Java является компилируемым языком. Так как запуск программы возможен только после сборки компилятором в модуль в более низкоуровневом представлении. То что этот низкоуровневый модуль не настолько близко к железу как с++ не делает java  не полностью компилируемым языком.